# Makefile -- do not rebuild order-only dependency if it already exists

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a does-not-exist-only target, such that a dependency's sub-dependencies are not considered if the dependency already exists.

That is, if I had the following:

```
A : | B
    @echo building $@
    @touch $@

B : C
    @echo build $@
    @touch $@

.PHONY: C 
C:
    @echo build $@
```

And then I do `make A; make A`.   In the first make it rebuilds `C`, `B`, then `A`.   In the second invocation, it still rebuilds `C` and `B` even though it doesn't need to in order to build `A`.   I'd like to short-circuit this such that it doesn't consider the dependencies of `B` if `B` already exists...

Comment: May be you can use `$(shell ...)` function to execute those commands unconditionally on each `make` invocation, rather than packing those commands into a phony target which triggers all its dependencies.

Comment: But if I did `make D`, then I wouldn't want `A`, `B` or `C`'s recipes to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it.

One way is to use Recursive Make ***(DUHN-DUHN-DUHNNNN!)***

```
B :
    @$(MAKE) C
    @echo build $@
    @touch $@
```

Or you could turn C from a rule to a recipe:

```
define c-steps
    @echo build C
    @echo with all the steps that C entails
endef

B :
    $(call c-steps)
    @echo build $@
    @touch $@
```

Comment: Unfortunately, mine is a really simplified example.   In reality, B is a series of large components that each have a web of dependencies below them.   Having said this, a recursive make would likely be the best solution for this.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: In that case... what does `C` actually do? Maybe you could use a dummy file as the target of that rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
A : | B
    @echo building $@
    @touch $@

B : $(if $(filter B,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),C) | C
    @echo build $@
    @touch $@

C:
    @echo build $@
    @touch $@
```

Your dependency `B : C` only applies when you wish to make `B` explicitly. The caveat of this is that it works only if you remove the phoniness of `C`.

Comment: But, if `B` doesn't exist (i.e. the first build), it would not build `C` if you did a `make A`..

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Yes you are right. The problem can be remedied by making `B` also order-only depend on `C` if (but only if) `C` is no longer `.PHONY`.